# Falsificate X509 signature

Tags: cryptography, openssl, rsa

Suppose we have two x509 certificates - client and server.

Is it possible to change some fields of client certificate (CN for example) and recalculate signature using server's public key (wich is known) in such a way that server will accept and successfuly verify client certificate?

In public key cryptography **private** key can encrypt and decrypt, **public** key encrypt only. So it seems that anyone who knows public key can recalculate signature and modify certificate?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In public key cryptography **private** key **signs** and **decrypts** and **public** key **verifies** and **encrypts**. You cannot perform both operation without having both keys.

Although, you are right that signing in case of RSA is essentially encryption with the private key, but since you don't posses private key you cannot re-sign certificate.

Comment: But if I can not resign without private key, how can I check signature? F.e. CA signs certificate by it's private key and include signature in client certificate in signature field just below signatureAlgorythm field. How then anybody can check that this signature is valid? They must COMPARE it with something...

Comment: One verifies signature with public key, which is known to anyone. Hence the name. Client decrypts hash of certificate with public key and compare with hash it calculated on its own. If they match then signature is valid. It's very different with DSA or ECC keys, although.

Comment: cat encrypted-by-private | openssl rsautl -decrypt -in public.key -pubin
"A private key is needed for this operation"

Comment: If openssl doesn't allow you to decrypt with public RSA key it doesn't mean it cannot be done. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/rsa-encryption-with-private-key-and-decryption-with-a-public-key?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I can not agree with those answers... The two keys (e,m) and (d,m) in the RSA key pair are fully equivalent.. No.. You can generate public component from private but not vise versa. So I am not shure they are right...

Comment: Public key is known to anyone. Then If anyone can produce a signature/certificate, what is value in signature/certificate?

Comment: Sorry yu were right. SIgn, verify, enc, decr was a ittle bit confusing.